# How to reduce a deeply nested json object by concatenating object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested json object like this:

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": "1",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "categoryId": "2",
        "subcategories": [
          {
            "categoryId": "3",
            "subcategories": [
              {
                "categoryId": "4"
              },
              {
                "categoryId": "5"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "categoryId": "6"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    // another category object
  }
]
```

**Note**, not all categories have sub-categories (some categories are 2-level deep and some 3 level).

I want to traverse the entire tree and print out **all** the `categoryId` in this structure (order is not important).
i.e. output should be something like: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

I came up with this one-liner:

`json.map(a => a.subCategories.map(b => b.subCategories ? b.subCategories.map(c => c.subCategories ? c.subCategories.map(d => d.categoryId) : c.categoryId) : b.categoryId)).join()`

But this is not printing `categoryId` contained in the top-level categories. I made several attempts at using `reduce` as well, but those were even worse. Could you please help me fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a tree structure, you can recursive loop through it
depth-first tree traversal

```js
let arr = [{
        "categoryId": "1",
        "subcategories": [{
            "categoryId": "2",
            "subcategories": [{
                    "categoryId": "3",
                    "subcategories": [{
                            "categoryId": "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "categoryId": "5"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "categoryId": "6"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "1",
        "subcategories": [{
            "categoryId": "2",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "categoryId": "8"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]

let result = [];

let loop = (cat) => {
    if (cat.categoryId) result.push(cat.categoryId) // to handle first undefined
    if (!cat.subcategories || cat.subcategories.length === 0) return;

    cat.subcategories.forEach(cat => loop(cat));
}

let fakeRoot = {
    subcategories: arr
}; // create fake root

loop(fakeRoot) // initialise 
console.log(result) // all cordinates 
console.log([...new Set(result)]) // uniqe values
```